# wiring two inverters/charger at the same battery bank

Tags: solar-charge-controller

I have 30 solar panels charging 12 batteries (48V system, 4 12V batteries in series ×3 ). 230 W / V=36.4V \$I_{\text{SC}}=8.56\,\text{A}\$

My problem is that I have not found a solar charger for the configuration
3 panels in series with 10 branches.
The open circuit voltage is 109.2 V
and short circuit current is 85.6A.

My questions:

- Can I use two inverter/chargers for the same battery bank?
- Is it possible to use two charge controllers to charge the same battery bank?

Comment: Current sharing could be unstable with same battery bank and would require special design. But very stable if all on float Vdc voltage

Comment: What is your load V,A, Wh?

Comment: I would go for two or more separate charge controllers and split the solar array accordingly.